# How to go back to the parent table view?

Tags: iphone

my iPhone application consists of a Tab bar controller with several navigation controllers within it, with table views in each of them.

I want it so that after I click on a tab bar item, if I go deeper into the table hierarchy and then click on another tab bar item, if I return back to the tab bar item before, that it goes back to the parent table.

Is there a method to somehow do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `[navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO]` when a tab is selected?